# NodeJS. How to create and save pdfs on the fly

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

i have a form with multiple inputs. The user should insert all inputs and send it. If the form is send a PDF should be created with the inputs informations and the pdf should be saved on the Server (No display is needed).

My Question is now, if somebody knew a good plugin/ module for node.JS which can
1) Create PDF with input informations
2) Save this PDF (on Server) (This can maybe be handled with fs)

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code whenever you run the node server it saves the pdf file into your directory from where you are running the server.Hope this helps for you.

```
var express=require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/nodejs/tasks/file.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };
var app=express();

var file=fs.writeFileSync('C:/Users/nodejs/tasks/businesscar.pdf');
app.get('/file',function(request,response)
{
pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscaw.pdf', function(err, res) {
if (err) return console.log(err);
console.log(res);
var file= 'C:/Users/nodejs/tasks/businesscaw.pdf';
fs.readFile(file,function(err,data){
    response.contentType("application/pdf");
    response.send(data);
});
});
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Server listening on port http://loalhost:3000");
});
```

See the output in browser :

```
localhost:3000/file
```

Comment: i have tested html-pdf and it works great, but is it possible to insert my inputs into the pdf?

Comment: I've ended to use pdfkit- Works great.

Comment: How you insert input values in pdf file?After the html file converted into pdf

Comment: Sry 4 the late responed: I use PDFKit and create a PDF on the fly without HTML

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe: Can I write file without `var html = fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/nodejs/tasks/file.html', 'utf8');` statement ?

Comment: I am having MEAN application, so I want to hit API `https://locallhost:3000/api/invoice` and then write that data to pdf files.

Comment: @mayank here reading a html file and converting into pdf without taking into variable how can we convert??

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe: okay, but for that first I have save `HTML` page, then write that to pdf file?

Comment: Then with this code whenver you hit the api new pdf will be created.Better to search for directly store in pdf and whenever api hits try to append that data to created pdf

Comment: okay, but still from where `html` page will come?

Comment: You can have a look on this link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523051/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-node-js-using-html-pdfmodule`

Comment: KK I am working on it.I will tell u when I get anything related to this

Comment: Is it ok for u that getting html form with one api and after entering data that data will be created as pdf whenever new data is enetered with html form new pdf will be created with that data

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe: Yes, that would work.

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe: Hi Ayesha, any success on generating the pdf? :)

Comment: @mayankbisht Here is my github link https://github.com/Syedayesha/pdfkit I pushed all files init you just clone it .Server file is **pdfkit.js** and run the server as **node pdfkit.js** after open the browser and type **http://localhost:3000/api/file**