# How to convert html to pdf in node.js using `html-pdf`module

Tags: node.js

I am generating invoice using `html-pdf` module.
I am able to generate pdf when I am passing web page local address, i.e stored in folder.
But my requirement is to hit API, and then generate pdf file.

*Can I do that using `html-pdf` module, or there is some other module that can do that?*

**Code**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
});
```

Please help.

Comment: You want to pass the html within your request ?

Comment: I want to hit API `http://localhost:3000/product/invoice`, in order to generate pdf.

Comment: And what specific problem you got ?

Comment: Problem is I don't want to save & pass html file as an input to `html-pdf` module

Answer (score 4):

If I'm reading this correctly, you want to generate a pdf from the html file, and then return it to the browser/client?

This should do it:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');

app.post('/product/invoice', function (req, res) {
    var htmlPath = req.body.htmlPath;
    if (!htmlPath){
        res.status(400).send("Missing 'htmlPath'");
        return;
    }
    var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlPath, 'utf8');
    // you may want to change this path dynamically if you also wish to keep the generated PDFs
    var pdfFilePath = './businesscard.pdf';
    var options = { format: 'Letter' };

    pdf.create(html, options).toFile(pdfFilePath, function(err, res2) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Some kind of error...");
            return;
        }
        fs.readFile(pdfFilePath , function (err,data){
            res.contentType("application/pdf");
            res.send(data);
        });
    });
});
```

You need to POST to this endpoint with *htmlPath* as a parameter (which will be, from your initial example, *./test/businesscard.html*) - make sure this is properly URL encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');`, this line still requires physical path of html page, how can I pass API data too`html-pdf` module?

Comment: Ah, you didn't make that clear. I will edit my answer after I've finished my lunch :-)

Comment: My requirement is to hit API, that API will return data, and I want to write that data to pdf file.

Comment: Hang on, let me get this straight. You're hitting the API and you want it to return data, and then you want to do something AFTER you've returned from the API? That won't be possible, you can only return once. If you want to pass in a path for an html file to the endpoint I defined, and then have that returned as a PDF file, that I can do. Let me know if that is what you are after.

Comment: okay, my endpoint `http://localhost:3000/product/invoice`, it will return HTML page filled with data. Now I want to pass this API to generate pdf file.

Comment: So you want two endpoints? One which returns the html content, and then you want to fire that content into a second API which will process and then return a PDF?

Comment: I've edited my answer so that everything you need is done by one endpoint. If you really need two, feel free to split out that functionality into two endpoints.

Comment: Again thanks for the updated code, but now I am getting `htmlPath` as undefined.I am having `get` request instead of `post`. Also, I am using `MEAN` stack. So I am hitting `/products/invoice` from the angular Js.

Comment: @HomerPlata: It's not working, can you help me out please?

Comment: @HomerPlata      Help me please.

Comment: Change app.post to app.get and then look into how to receive parameters from a GET request instead of using req.body.{param name}. What is the full URL path you are trying to use?

Comment: @HomerPlata it is not opening in the browser

Answer (score 1):

You can send the created pdf file to the client **without saving the file in the root directory of your project**:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const pdf = require('html-pdf');

app.get('invoice/generatePDF', (req, res, next) => {

    const html = fs.readFileSync('./template.html').toString() // './test/businesscard.html'
    var options = { format: 'Letter' };

    pdf.create(html, options).toStream(function (err, stream) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Some kind of error...");
            return;
        }
        stream.pipe(res)
    })

})
```

If you want to use **html-pdf** in nestjs, first of all **import** `Res` from `@nestjs/common` and `Response` from `express` then

```
import { Controller, Get, InternalServerErrorException, Req, Res, } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as pdf from 'html-pdf'
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import { Response, Request } from 'express';


@Controller()
export class AppController {

  @Get()
  async convertHtmlToPDF(@Res() response: Response) {
    const html = readFileSync('./public/index.html').toString()
    var options = { format: 'Letter' };

    pdf.create(html, options).toStream(function (err, stream) {
      if (err) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException({ status: 500, messsage: "Some kind of error..." })
      }
      stream.pipe(response)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i apply this logic in nestjs

Comment: @Ashin Thankachan - I updated the answer, have a nice time.

Comment: hai i am working on the previously created project. in that project for "res" created like this

```
............
 const result = await this.estimateDao.genarateEstPdf(
      customer,
      company,
      estimate_uid,
      logger,
      res
    );
    return result.makeResponse(res);
......
``` 
instead of this stream.pipe(response) what should I do?

Comment: this is the result response 


````
export class ResultResponse {
  readonly status: ResponseStatus;
  private response_data: IResponseData | Buffer;

  constructor(
    status: ResponseStatus = ResponseStatus.SUCCESS,
    response_data: IResponseData | Buffer
  ) {
    this.status = status;
    this.response_data = response_data;
  }

  makeResponse(@Res() res) {
    console.log(this.response_data,"response data")
    res.status(this.status);
    return res.send(this.response_data);
  }
}